# Flexi_ath not compatible with Codeigniter3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upgrade a Codeigniter project to CI3 however I am having trouble with the flex_auth security library

I am trying to upgrade a system to CI3 however I cannot get FlexiAuth to work with it. When I try and load Flexi_auth I get the following error

> Severity: Error
>   
> Message: Class ‘CI_Flexi_auth_lite’ not found
>   
> Filename: core/Common.php
>   
> Line Number: 185

I presume this is because it can’t find Flexi_auth_lite in the libraries folder so it goes on to look for it in the system libraries? Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in this. The answer is provided on the codeigniter forums:
http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-977-page-2.html?highlight=flexiauth
https://github.com/leap-it/Flexi-Auth-and-Codeigniter-3RC2

Answer (score 0):

Replace load_class('Flexi_auth_lite', 'libraries', FALSE);
with include_once('Flexi_auth_lite.php');